# MKLocalSearchCompleter not working on physical device but works fine on simulator

Tags: swift, delegates, mapkit, geocoding, core-location

I am stuck with very strange issue with my app. When I run a MKLocalSearchCompleter request on a simulator it works fine, delegate methods are called and everything runs smoothly.

But, when trying on a physical device, delegate methods are not called anymore (neither didUpdateResults(_ :) nor didFailWithError(_ :))

I have tried to test the same implementation on a brand new project; same behaviour.

When I geocode an address with CLGeocoder it works fine on both physical and simulator.

My network is very good and every other networking tasks work well.

My implementation is very basic:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        let searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()

        searchCompleter.delegate = self

        searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.text!

}
func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        print(completer.results)

        searchQueryResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()

        completer.results.forEach { (result) in
            self.searchQueryResults!.append(result)
        }

        researchTable.alpha = 1.0
        researchTable.reloadData()
}
func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
}
```

Really I have been searching for a while and wasn't able to find an answer; Thank a lot for helping me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it is worked or not but it is just hinted for you.

Just define `let searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()` globally in your UIViewController.

Write the below statement `viewDidLoad` methods instead of delegate methods.

```
 let searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()

 searchCompleter.delegate = self
```

I was dealing with same type of issue in the past When I was working with `UIImagePickerController`. It is worked for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Whoa super strange... Why the different behaviour between simulator and device ? Anyway, thanks a lot  for your help ;)

Comment: As per my knowledge, Ther is nothing related to a device or simulator, It is an iOS 11 and above issue. ARC automatically releases the local instance if no longer required. Same code is worked in iOS 9.0. Glad to hear my answer helpful for you!. Thank you and Happy coding